# Nuxt - How to call a getters in a global mixins?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, mixins

Hi everyone here is the mixin code I wrote as I want to use this for default.vue and error.vue layout. I am trying to avoid duplicating code in two layout.

```
export default {
  provide () {
    return {
      copyRight: this.getCopyrightText,
      email: this.getEmail,
      socials: this.getSocials
    }
  },
  computed: {
    getMenu () {
      return this.store.getters['general/getMenu'].menu
    },

    getSocials () {
      return this.store.getters['general/getSocialDetails']
    },

    getCopyrightText () {
      return this.store.getters['general/getCopyRight']
    },

    getEmail () {
      return this.store.getters['general/getEmail']
    }
  },
  middleware: 'load-menu-items'
}
```

This is what I get: **Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your component I assume you're using `.length` on the data you're receiving from the getter method, which is probably where the error occurs.

First of all you should debug to see if your getter is actually working as expected. Try this and look at output in console for every getter computed property. If `undefined` is printed to the console you'll get the error you posted if you're using `.length` on it

```
getEmail () {
  let data = this.store.getters['general/getEmail'];
  console.log(data);
  return data;
}
```

If you post the component which is using this mixin maybe I can help you further.

Comment: ah its my mistake i forgot to add ``` the this.$store ``` instead it is working now.